# How to store PT Update Event for a sheet that gets deleted/recreated on opening?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, pivot-chart

Yesterday I wrote a VBA code within the Microsoft Object folder and within a sheet to reformat a pivot chart after filtering using Worksheets_PivotTableUpdate event and a private sub. It was working great!

I closed and reopened the file yesterday and it was gone, and the filtering didn't trigger the code despite it working when the VBA was open. I went to look in the sheet and there's no code there. I thought I had forgot to save or saved incorrectly so I wrote it again and this morning when I opened the file again... formatting after filtering code doesn't work, no code to be found. So... where is it? Why isn't it saving?

Multiple people will be using this file so I can't just redo it every time I need to, and plus it doesn't make sense for it to just disappear every time the file is closed/reopened. I know a lot of code for working in VBA and especially with PivotTables/Charts, but I'd still consider myself a beginner.

I am going to rewrite the code so I will post when I finish. This is the code that formats the pivot chart originally. The sheet code readds the data labels, adds some borders, and changes the size of the donut hole.

EDIT: I figured out the issue and it is a silly one. When the workbook macro runs, it deletes the sheet where the other code is stored. Here's my new question... how else can I store this so this doesn't happen?

Dim pc_utl As Chart
    Dim chart_rng_2 As Range
        Set chart_rng_2 = wsu.Range("B10:F35") 'Where to place Donut Chart on sheet

```
With chart_rng_2
    Set pc_utl = wsu.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height).Chart 'Creates donut chart if it doesn't exist already
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With pc_utl
    .ChartType = xlDoughnut 'Sets chart type to donut
    .ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowPercent 'Labels donut slices with % data from PTable
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = title_formula_2 'Dynamic chart title
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    .PlotBy = xlColumns
    .DoughnutGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = 25
End With
Else 'Refresh PivotTable and PivotChart if they exist already
    pt_utl.ChangePivotCache pivot_cache_2
    pt_utl.RefreshTable
End If
```

Here's the code stored in the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
If Target = "%Utilization" Then
    With Worksheets("Utilization")
        With .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
            .ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowPercent
        End With
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you save the file as a macro enabled spreadsheet (.xlsm)?

Comment: Yes, it's always been saved as such. This workbook with VBA code has been active and working for a couple of months. This is the first time I've had a problem with losing code. I am wondering if it has something to do with writing in the sheets but I don't know how to fit this. Thanks

Comment: The code not being retained doesn't sound like a problem with the code itself... something else is going on.

Comment: @BigBen Okay, so just to confirm, even if the code was in the sheet and not within the modules that control the whole workbook, it should still be there when the file is closed/reopened...? I just want to make sure it's not just me haha

Comment: Is there code in the `BeforeSave` or `BeforeClose` event? That may be cancelling the saving of the file when closed?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I don't have BeforeSave or BeforeClose anywhere in my code. I am just saving and closing the file manually when I am done for the day.